# Is order of enumeration important in XML Schema

Tags: xml, xsd

I need to know when XML Schema enumeration is important. I know for validation it is does not make sense if we change the order of the enumerated values. For example this code:

```
<simpleType name="sizeType">
    <restriction base="string">
        <enumeration value="small"/>
        <enumeration value="medium"/>
        <enumeration value="large"/>
    </restriction>
</simpleType>
```

is similar to this code:

```
<simpleType name="sizeType">
    <restriction base="string">
        <enumeration value="small"/>
        <enumeration value="large"/>
        <enumeration value="medium"/>
    </restriction>
</simpleType>
```

In terms of the validity of the related XML documents.

My question is: what are possible applications that makes the order important because I am designing XML change detection method and not sure if I need to take the order of enumerated values in my account.

Appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess there may be data binding tools that convert the XSD enumeration into an enumeration type in the target language, in which case the order might be significant, but as far as XSD validation is concerned, the order makes no difference.